# Fire an event in Android/AndEngine?

Tags: android, events, andengine

I have a 'trick' that I do sometimes in Java/Swing in which I create a swing component that is always invisible and have property change event listener(s) attached to it. When a variable(s) changes value, the code will cause that component to change and fire an event and anything listening will know that those variable(s) have changed.

I want to do this same thing in Android or AndEngine. What would I use instead of the swing component? I'm was thinking of overriding some subclass of `org.andengine.entity.Entity`, but I don't see any event to fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you almost hit on it with your Swing idea. There is no event pattern built into andengine, and the reason for this is probably because of the event classes built into the android operating system.

You should have good luck implementing a Listener (Observer Pattern) into your app following the steps in this other Stack Overflow answer:
[Custom event listener on Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983250/custom-event-listener-on-android-app)

or this simple example in which the broadcaster call a function on a single listener:
[Android - event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352719/android-event-listener)

As a footnote, neither example includes code to REMOVE listeners. Be sure your implementation does include that so that you can garbage collect objects you don't need any more.